# Elastic search kibana installation

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I am trying to install elasticsearch in windows susbsytem for linux using ubuntu.
it had installed required packages while trying to connect elastic search it had thrown some errors like . how to fix this issue.

```
venkat@DESKTOP-4KU4062:~$ sudo /bin/systemctl daemon-reload
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
venkat@DESKTOP-4KU4062:~$ sudo /bin/systemctl enable elasticsearch.service
Synchronizing state of elasticsearch.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable elasticsearch
venkat@DESKTOP-4KU4062:~$ sudo /bin/systemctl start elasticsearch.service
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
venkat@DESKTOP-4KU4062:~$ sudo /bin/systemctl start elasticsearch.service
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
venkat@DESKTOP-4KU4062:~$ curl 127.0.0.1:9200
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 9200: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

try `sudo -i service elasticsearch start` and see if it's successful.

Answer (score 0):

Starting the service with 'systemctl' and 'service' is different for different operating system and also depends on their versions. It is basically based on the Ubuntu version you are using.

for this issue "System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.' :

use `sudo service daemon-reload start` in place of `sudo /bin/systemctl daemon-reload`

Replace the other service with daemon-reload in above command.